# Set UPN of AD users from result of Get-AdUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have some users in AD that have the UPN address set like `User@this.org`. I want to change those users so their UPN looks like that `User@that.com`.

I have written a PS line to find me such users:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(userPrincipalName=*@this.org))" -SearchBase "OU=this,DC=that"  | Select SamAccountName
```

But how do I update those users. I know about `Set-AdUser` command, but I can't figure out how to feed the result of the `Get-Aduser` into it.

Comment: Just pipe to `Set-ADUser` instead of `Select`

Comment: Sorry Mathias, I'm new to PS - do you mean I delete Select and Write Set-Aduser? Won't that just change one user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pipe it to `Set-ADUser`:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(userPrincipalName=*@this.org))" -SearchBase "OU=this,DC=that" | % {Set-ADUser $_ -UserPrincipalName "that"}
```

Just a heads up, use `-Whatif` during testing before you crash you whole AD.

**Explanation:**

`%` - Alias for foreach

`$_` - Equals each object of the `foreach` (each User found in the `Get-ADuser`)

`-UserPrincipalName "that"` - Set the UPN of the given User to `that`

Comment: Perhaps instead of using the % alias, write foreach. This can make it easier for a newcomer to read and understand the code :)

Comment: @HenrikStanleyMortensen yeah you're right. I added a small explanation.